# Add onClick dynamically using JavaScript get multiple same action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe i can't write all code here, but i think this is can explain my problem :

```js
for(var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
  $('#mybutton').on('click', function() { return false; });
  $('#mybutton').on('click', function() { myfunction('123') });
}

function myfunction(text){
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id = 'mybutton'> My Button </button>
```

And the result :

I get `myfunction` executed 5 times.

**My Question is** :

How to avoid myfunction executed 5 times (i want to execute it 1 time) without remove looping for cause i need it for my case? I try to remove the onClick event but not working.

Thank you

Comment: Just click once :D

Comment: Binding event **10** times on same element in `for`. Just remove `for`.

Comment: Or if you can't remove the `for`, just bind the event *outside* it

Comment: What is the purpose of your `for` loop?

Comment: i think i speak for everyone.... please explain why the for loop is needed...

Comment: Your code wouldn't invoke the click, it just binds a callback function to the `click` event 10 times.. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is nothing here which needs to be 'dynamically' as title suggests.

Comment: Sorry, in real case i'm not use looping, but cause i hard to explain if i write in a long code so i find something that close enough to my case. Anyway thank you for your response. Your solutions are really awesome, i appreciate for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm not sure why you realy need to attach event inside the for loop) but you could dettach the click event before attaching the next one using jQuery method **[`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**.

> **`off()` :** Remove an event handler.

**Example :**

```
$('#mybutton').off('click').on('click', function() { myfunction('123') });
```

Hope this helps.

```js
for(var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
  $('#mybutton').off('click').on('click', function() { myfunction('123') });
}

function myfunction(text){
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id = 'mybutton'> My Button </button>
```

Comment: Seems completely unnecessary to me.

Comment: To me too, but the OP says _without remove looping for cause i need it for my case_ so i'm trying to answer it.

Comment: I think this is the best answer though, it seems the cleanest way.. lol. I was trying to find something like `.once();` incase that existed and apply that, but it would probably still loop over it and run it 5 times. x)

Comment: And you've missed `return false;` in event handler.

Answer (score 1):

The following logic can be better :

```js
const myfunction = function (a) {console.log(a)};

const callback1 = function() { return false; };
const callback2= function() { myfunction('123') }; 

 $('#mybutton').on('click', function (event) {
     for (var i=0 ; i<=5 ; i++) {
       callback1();
       callback2();
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="mybutton">click me</button>
```

Comment: I don't see the use of `callback1` here, it just returns `false` from it. Note: It doesn't prevent default action and event bubbling of clicked element.

Comment: sure the question owner does not disclose his code and want the idea in general .. I am sure `callback1` in reality contains another logic

Comment: What I mean is `$('#mybutton').on('click', function() { return false; });` will stop event bubbling to it's parent. While in your code, it'll not. To make it do same as OP's code, add `return callback1()` to the end of event handler. And I don't even see why you created new function which returns false from there(_assuming that is the only code in that function_).

Comment: @Tushar: I am really thankful for this info . I was not aware about that until you told me .

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    $('#mybutton').on('click', function() { return false; });
    if (i == 0)
        $('#mybutton').on('click', function() { myfunction('123') });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have something more dynamic & elegant & over-engineered , you can use `Tasks` class as following, assuming all callbacks receive the same arguments :

```js
class Tasks {
  constructor(...tasks) {
   this.tasks = tasks;
  }
  
  run(times, ...args) {
    return Array.from({length: times}, (v, k) => k+1).map(iteration => 
      this.tasks.map(task => task(...args))                   )

  }

}

const myfunction = function (a) {console.log(a)};
const callback1 = function() { return false; };
const callback2= function() { myfunction('123') }; 


 $('#mybutton').on('click', function (event) {
     new Tasks(callback1, callback2)
       .run(5, event);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutton">click me</button>
```